# Interpreting mutrace output

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have implemented multi-threaded software application that captures low-level ethernet packet data (using `pcap`) and places those packets into a ring buffer. In a separate thread packets are removed from the ring buffer and processed.

I.e. I have a LIFO queue with one thread adding data and another taking it out.

Performance analysis has shown that the ring buffer quickly fills up, i.e. packets cannot be removed as fast as they are being added. Even when I comment out all of the processing in the thread taking the packets, i.e. the application is reduced to simply adding and taking packets and performing no other processing.

One thing I thought could be causing the problem was mutex lock contention on the queue.

I ran the application with `mutrace` and got the following output:

```
mutrace: Showing 2 most contended mutexes:

Mutex #   Locked  Changed    Cont. tot.Time[ms] avg.Time[ms] max.Time[ms]  Flags
   6    27740      209       35       75.672        0.003       59.944 M-.--.
   5       19       13        0        0.021        0.001        0.004 M-.--.
```

This seems to suggest that contention on the mutex used for adding/taking packets (mutex 6) is not too bad, only 0.1% of the locks have been contentious. The only thing that seems to stand out is the huge difference between the avg. lock time and the max lock time. Has anyone else noticed huge disparities in lock times? Possibly its just an anomaly of mutrace and not something to be concerned about?

Comment: Is it possible for a thread to be pre-empted while it holds the lock? Try re-running with high priority in the FIFO scheduling class, with both threads bound to un-contended cores. If possible also make sure those cores won't be used for servicing interrupts.

Comment: i'm not sure how to do the things you mention, but they sound very sensible - any relevant links to get me started? OS is ubuntu 16.04 and I haven't mucked about with any realtime kernel settings

Comment: Interestingly when the packet taking/processing occurs in the main (parent?) thread then I rarely see the ring buffer fill up. Its much more problematic when the packet taking/processing occurs in a child thread. The packet adding always occurs in a child thread

Comment: Take a look at the `pthreads` man page, it should refer you to the `sched_setscheduler` etc. functions for scheduling policy and priority, and CPU affinity. If you have a multi-socket (NUMA) machine, you want to make sure both threads are bound to cores on the same socket. Use `numactl` in that case to control which node your memory is allocated on.

Comment: CPU is bog standard Intel® Core™ i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4 so prob not multi-socket (NUMA)?

Comment: If you have one CPU, it's not NUMA. Multi-socket means a CPU in each socket, so you can ignore the `numactl` bit.